# Include Gutenberg scss Variables in Custom Gutenberg Block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I use the [create-guten-block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block) repo to create a nice ES6-enabled Gutenberg block for Wordpress. However I want to be able to use scss-variables that are defined in the gutenberg repository here:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_variables.scss

Unfortunately the assets cannot be installed via an npm package. So how would I include the variables in my custom gutenberg block? I want to do something like this in the block's `style.css`

```
import "~@wordpress/assets/styles/variables"
```

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: You migth have to configure webpack for the proper paths

Comment: https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/727 loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              "includePaths": [
                require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
              ]
            }

Comment: this is not exactly what you are looking for, but roots has a project called "bud", which enables the generation of the theme.json file. https://bud.js.org/extensions/sage#generate-themejson
It could help someone here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible unless you copied the exact file and referred to it like this inside your scss file

```
@import "./variables";
```

What you need to do is create `_variables.scss` inside the same folder as your main scss file is, then use the code above to import it. You'll have to go inside the file `_variables.scss` as well and make sure all variables are defined, meaning, import any dependency that is needed for this file. I'm pointing here to the `_colors.scss` dependency in the same folder, and that's all you need.

You can't use

```
import "~@wordpress/assets/styles/variables"
```

this won't work because you're trying to import an npm package, which does not recognize styles.

Answer (score 3):

### Install

`npm install @wordpress/base-styles --save-dev`

### Import

```
@import "node_modules/@wordpress/base-styles/colors";
@import "node_modules/@wordpress/base-styles/variables";
@import "node_modules/@wordpress/base-styles/mixins";
@import "node_modules/@wordpress/base-styles/breakpoints";
@import "node_modules/@wordpress/base-styles/animations";
@import "node_modules/@wordpress/base-styles/z-index";
```

They also support postCSS and a few other things, check here for the [full docs](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/03b1e8024f432843932057a3553b613cb52c450b/packages/base-styles).

Answer (score 0):

*If I understand your question correctly. You want to use SASS variables inside your custom Gutenberg block, right ?*

If you are using create-guten-block. You don't need to install anything. Just include your sass variable in that block's scss files.For example -

If this is your [block directory](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block/tree/master/examples/01-single-block/src/block) then inside style.scss and editor.scss put the SASS variables.

I hope this helps

Comment: I want to be able to use wordpress specific sass variables.

Comment: Your best bet would be to ask on GitHub, where the development is in progress. Create an issue here - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues